# Format in cl-who does't work properly

Tags: lisp, format, hunchentoot

I'm trying to build a personal Website via hunchentoot and cl-who, but I'm occurring an semantic error in the following code:

```
(defun index ()
  (standart-page (:title "~apb")
                 (dolist (article (articles))
                   (cl-who:htm
                    (:ul
                     (:li (format nil "~a: ~a" (article-date article) (article-title article))))))))
```

"standart-page" is a macro:

```
(defmacro standart-page ((&key title) &body body)   `(cl-who:with-html-output-to-string (*standart-output* nil :prologue t :indent t)
                               (:html :xmlns "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                                      :xml\:lang "de"
                                      :lang "de"
                                      (:head
                                       (:title ,title)
                                       (:body
                                        (:div :id "wrapper"
                                              (:div :id "header"
                                                    (:h1 "~apb"))
                                              (:div :id "content"
                                                    ,@body)))))))
```

The evaluation of "(index)" (with one test article in "(articles)" returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='de' lang='de'>
  <head>
    <title>
      ~apb
    </title>
    <body>
      <div id='wrapper'>
        <div id='header'>
          <h1>
            ~apb
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div id='content'>
          <ul>
            <li>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

By looking at the `<li>..</li>` tags I was wondering why there is no output. I think there's something wrong with the format function but I cant't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the examples of usage on the CL-WHO site I don't think you can just do a format that returns a string.  All of their examples either use custom output functions (for example fmt) that appear to write to a dynamic variable under the hood.  In the example of code generated by CL-WHO you see this as a `(format http-output-stream ....)` line in the macro expansion.

This would explain why you're not getting any output, you just need to use their custom output writers instead of the `(format nil ..)` that you're using.  You probably want something like

`(fmt "~a: ~a" (article-date article) (article-title article))`

Comment: Ok, thank you, but it gives me an error "Undefined function FMT". I'm not sure but could you please tell me in which package it is. (I haven't found anything useful)

Comment: It should be in package `cl-who`, I think. Either do `use-package` in your own package's definition, or try `cl-who:fmt`.

Comment: It's been a while since I've messed with `cl-who`, but IIRC `fmt` isn't a function.  It's just a symbol, and only meaningful inside a `with-html-output` expansion.

Answer (score 3):

For `format` specifically, Andrew's answer is the right one.  In general, you can use `str`:

```
CL-USER> (with-html-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
           (:p (str (format nil "~A" '<hello/>))))
"<p><HELLO/></p>"
```

Note that the string isn't HTML-escaped in this case (this goes for `fmt` as well).  If you want it to be, use `esc` instead:

```
CL-USER> (with-html-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
           (:p (esc (format nil "~A" '<hello/>))))
"<p>&lt;HELLO/&gt;</p>"
```

Similarly, use `htm` to get back into HTML mode when having escaped out of it:

```
CL-USER> (with-html-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
           (:ul (loop for x from 1 to 3
                      do (htm (:li (str x))))))
"<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>"
```

Answer (score 2):

One obvious mistake is that you misspelt "standard".  Therefore, binding a stream to `*standart-output*` (sic) does not re-bind `*standard-output*`, as you perhaps intended.